# Unable to invoke toDate() on primeng's calendar timestamp

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, primeng

I have the following value of a date (p-calendar) field:
t {seconds: 1623740410, nanoseconds: 0}
I want to invoke toDate() on a variable (with the above value contained in it) to initialize a form control on a reactive form. Below is the .ts code and .html code:

.ts

```
this.itemForm = new FormGroup({
  startDate: new FormControl(this.editItem.startDate?.toDate(), Validators.required),
});
```

.html

```
<p-calendar 
    [monthNavigator]="true"
    [yearNavigator]="true"
    yearRange="1980:2150"
    dateFormat="dd M yy" 
    placeholder="Select date*"
    [showIcon]="true"
    [showTime]="true"
    appendTo="body"
    formControlName="startDate">
</p-calendar>
```

The .ts code gives the following error:
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)

I tried fixing the problem by creating variables and first testing for null like so:

```
let startDate = null;
if (this.editItem.startDate) {
  startdate = this.editItem.startDate.toDate();
}
```

but no luck. I even tried to pass the timestamp to new Date(timestamp) and also no luck.

This used to always work in my projects. I run on "@angular/core": "~11.2.1" and "primeng": "^11.3.1". Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Here's an image of a screenshot the contains the value of editItem:  [image: image of screenshot that contains editItem]

Comment: what is `this.editItem` ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, it's an object where startDate: t {seconds: 1623740410, nanoseconds: 0}

Comment: Are you sure .toDate() is available for editItem ?@ClintTheron

Comment: I fixed it by using unary if. Example, ...(this.editItem.startDate.toDate ? this.editItem.startDate() : new Date(),...). Thank you for your interest